Tailwind css isn't working in react native
<View className="flex-1 items-center justify-center bg-white">
  <Text className="text-3xl">Hello World!</Text>
  

tailwind css isn't working in react native . It shows in topleft corner of the screen in mobile
i  tried installing all the required components  like


npm install nativewind
npm install tailwindcss --save-dev
npx tailwindcss init
npm update tailwindcss nativewind
added tailwindcss config


content: ["./app//*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./components//*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
added plugins: ["nativewind/babel"] in bable file

Adding the Babel preset module:metro-react-native-babel-preset is essential for your React Native project. It allows Babel to transform your code correctly for the React Native environment, enabling support for JSX and modern JavaScript features.
Here’s how your Babel configuration should look:
module.exports = {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
    plugins: ['nativewind/babel'],
};

